# Find collection in a Sharky offer loan transaction

Tags: instructions, transaction-instructions

I'm trying to analyze a transaction for the NFT Lending protocol Sharky.fi.

This txn for example : [Cm4pCJFCKQzmtuZ254itotMokhK8X6zs7YfeWKYE6i8kpaowZ3XzUPWJbhvvcoZ6KxULP79PEBy8A3P4nmPpkgg](https://solscan.io/tx/Cm4pCJFCKQzmtuZ254itotMokhK8X6zs7YfeWKYE6i8kpaowZ3XzUPWJbhvvcoZ6KxULP79PEBy8A3P4nmPpkgg)

We have an OfferLoan instruction, but I'd like to know which collection is this offer for.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Looks like you would need to read each of the accounts included in the transaction, then parse the data from there. I would ask in their project discord to get specific help with their contract

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 7th input account of the OfferLoan instruction is unique per collection.

In the above transaction, it's [7FbuhkNjvis2wk3vxu9jpeHjgxpr2Myyw9vmnbVWoPLT](https://solscan.io/account/7FbuhkNjvis2wk3vxu9jpeHjgxpr2Myyw9vmnbVWoPLT).

To match a collection, search in Sharky source code and find :

```
{
    orderBookPubKey: "7FbuhkNjvis2wk3vxu9jpeHjgxpr2Myyw9vmnbVWoPLT",
    collectionName: "y00ts"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

should probably ask this in the sharkyfi discord. doesn't look like any of the accounts on that transaction include NFTs or NFT token accounts so hard to tell.